# CAPM - Do I use start or end of period prices?

Tags: finance, asset-pricing, capm

If I use monthly price data in the standard CAPM, should I take the price at the beginning or the end of the month? What is the convention? Or does it not matter? Is there any literature that deals explicitly with this subject?

Thank you

Comment: More importantly, the CAPM does not deal with _prices_ but with _expected returns_, so you need two price points to calculate the (expected) returns.

Answer (score 1):

The most common approach is to calculate returns as $r_t=\frac{p_t-p_{t-1}}{p_{t-1}}$ or $r_t=ln\left (\frac{p_t}{p_{t-1}}\right)$ using close prices at the end of the month.

Answer (score 0):

It's most common to use end of the period figures. However, it should not matter as long as you're consequent. Further, the end of period metric will be very similar to the measure at the beginning of the next period.